# JSX onClick event seems to be clicked on default

Tags: reactjs, events, jsx

I think I am doing something stupid. I have some code and can't figure out why its not working how I expect it to.

I expect the terminal to log to the terminal when the button / link is clicked but it seems to do it regardless

Code below

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import DataExample from './dataExample'

export default class home extends Component {
  state = {
    name:"Joy",
    place:"nirvana"
  }

consoleLog = (e) =>{
   return console.log("just clicked")
}


  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h3>This is my homepage that contains components</h3>

        <a href="#" onClick={this.consoleLog("link clicked")}>My Button</a>

      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Actual result shows the console.log proir to my clicking button [image]

Comment: Its because you already invoked the function ``` this.consoleLog("link clicked") ``` either pass the reference like this ``` this.consoleLog``` or ```() => this.consoleLog("link clicked")```

Answer (score 1):

Currently you are calling the this.consoleLog() in the code instead of passing it.

This should work:

```
<a href="#" onClick={() => this.consoleLog("link clicked")}>My Button</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

`consoleLog()` is calling on the render

```
    return (
      <div>
        <h3>This is my homepage that contains components</h3>

        <a href="#" onClick={() => this.consoleLog("link clicked")}>My Button</a>

      </div>
    )
  }
```